# iOS 15 beta device - app needs to be updated

Tags: ios, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I am using a ios 15 beta device. When I try and download the app from app center I get the error 'xxx needs to be updated'.

How can I download the app and test it on a iOS 15 device?

I am building my app using RN 64.2 and xcode 12.4

[image]

Comment: Did you try to build your app on Xcode12.5?

Comment: Yes I still get the prompt, any ideas?

Comment: If you've signed your app using an Enterprise certificate, then the solution is probably the same as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69287653/4894980

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, tried all the solutions about Xcode version and the provisioning profile, but nothing helped. Finally, this worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66710689/11613742