# "The Developer of this app needs to update it to work with this version of iOS" pop up coming when launching Enterprise app for iOS 15

Tags: xcode, enterprise, ios15

We have an enterprise account, and till iOS 14 there were no issues, but as soon as user update their phones to iOS 15, they are getting this alert.

[The Developer of this app needs to update it to work with this version of iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzq5q.jpg)

Now, this issue is coming only for enterprise apps running on iOS 15. I have done some research and found this article. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/using-the-latest-code-signature-format.

In here it states that

> To check whether an app called MyApp.app has the new signature, you
> can use the

> > codesign utility:
> > % codesign -dv /path/to/MyApp.app

> Look in the output for a string such as CodeDirectory v=20500. For any
> value of v less than 20400, you need to re-sign your app.

I did that and my output was indeed v=20400. I have signed the app using Xcode 12.5 running on Mac OS 11.2.3. I don't think Apple documents are correct for this. (I could be wrong)

Can anyone please help and let me know, what exactly we need to do to get this issue fixed?

EDIT:
I was able to solve this issue by upgrading OS to Big Sur. Xcode version was 12.5.

Comment: Did you try by first creating a new provisioning profile?
Did you check if you have extensions/bundles/frameworks in your code that also need to be resigned?

Comment: I did not check for provisioning profile. Let me do that

Comment: The builds need to be generated from BigSur for iOS 15 and may require updating the provisioning profile.

Comment: I'm using Bitrise and needed to select the 'Xcode 12.5.x, on macOS 11.4 (Big Sur)' Stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had same issue, use xcode 13.0 to build the ipa. It should work.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `codesign -d --verbose=5 your_app.app`, how many lines do you see in the "page size" block? Do you see a `-7=` line? If so, does it contain no value (or 0)?

If there is no `-7=` line (or it has no value) then your app does not include the DER entitlements and you will need to re-sign. You might need a new provisioning profile.

Comment: This is the output I am getting

Format=app bundle with Mach-O universal (armv7 arm64)
CodeDirectory v=20400 size=56208 flags=0x0(none) hashes=1748+5 location=embedded
Signature size=4888
Signed Time=24-Mar-2021 at 8:11:26 PM
Info.plist entries=40
TeamIdentifier=G9LC2XRFX8
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=10 files=413
Internal requirements count=1 size=192
surbhitthanvi@Surbhits-MacBook-Pro ~ %

Comment: Sorry, that is unreadable. Can you past just the rows underneath `Page size`?

Comment: it does not print any page size block when I run the command

Comment: Can you copy and paste the command you type and the output again?

Comment: I used your command codesign -d --verbose=5 your_app.app . It does not show pagesize. It does show other information as @SurbhitThanvi mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Facing same issue, I have also go through using this and found helpful, read each and every steps carefully one of the solutions given on link will definitely work for you

https://wilbertech.com/blog/index.php/2021/10/03/ios-app-needs-to-be-updated/

Answer (score 1):

[image: You must be getting a popup like this for your App.]

**There may be two reasons for this.**

1:You are getting this error bcoz you are using old provisional profile, just need to regenerate the provisional profile and your app will work  fine.

2: You have added the arm64 in excluded architecture in  build setting, architecture just remove arm64 from the excluded architecture and do it only for simulator.
you can further check this link for 2nd reason.

[Xcode building for iOS Simulator, but linking in an object file built for iOS, for architecture 'arm64'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-ios-f/71840172#71840172)

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue in my app and followed below step to resolve it.
Xcode : 12.4
Mac OS : 10.15.7

In terminal run below command

% **codesign -s "Your Codesign Identity" -f --preserve-metadata --generate-entitlement-der /path/to/MyApp.app**

Also,Follow this link to get brief idea about this iOS related issue.
% codesign -s "Your Codesign Identity" -f --preserve-metadata --generate-entitlement-der /path/to/MyApp.app

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/using-the-latest-code-signature-format

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had this issue for iOS 15 and 16, no problem with iOS 13, we had not iOS 14 devices for testing. The problem appeared after implement a Framework, it was fixed by changing the embed option to **Do Not Embed** on General -> Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content