# App doesn't run on iOS 15 because it does not have valid signature format

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, expo

###### Issue

When I try to open app on iOS 15.6, it shows warning saying:
*The developer of this app needs to update it to work with this version of iOS.*

I generate .ipa file using archive feature in xCode. All signing should be handled by IDE. When I unzip .ipa file and run `codesign -dv /Payload/demo.app` it shows `CodeDirectory v=20200`, which should be `CodeDirectory v=20400` or higher judging by this article: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/using-the-latest-code-signature-format.

I have tried signing it manually, like it's mentioned in the article. Nothing has helped.

###### Software:

MacOS version: macOS Monterey 12.5 (21G72)
xCode version: 13.4.1 (13F100)

Comment: Please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69310775/the-developer-of-this-app-needs-to-update-it-to-work-with-this-version-of-ios

Comment: @Protocol They solved issue by updating their OS and xCode. Unfortunately i am working with recent versions, which should be alright...