# "The Developer of app needs to update it to work with this version of iOS" error when installing app on iPhone from appcenter through Azuredevops

Tags: ios, react-native, azure-pipelines

When I manually archive and create ipa file I am able to install it on my device. However, when I run the pipeline to install the same app having same provisioning profile I get this error. I have added below code in podfile for preventing pipeline error 65.
added code in pod file:

```
 installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER'] = ''
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = 'NO'
    end
    if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER'] = ''
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: May i know what agent do you use in the devops pipeline? And what's iOS version locally? As per the error, the app is NOT compatible with the iOS version on the agent. With `MacOS-13`, `MacOS-12`(macOS-latest) agents, it has `iOS 16` and `iOS 15`. Please give a try with `MacOS-11` agent. Please check the software details for agents in [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software) and [similar ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69310775/the-developer-of-this-app-needs-to-update-it-to-work-with-this-version-of-ios).

Comment: Running using MacOS-11 gave me below error **The following build commands failed:
 CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'lottie-react-native' from project 'Pods')
 CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'amplitude-react-native' from project 'Pods')
 CompileSwift normal arm64 (in target 'amplitude-react-native' from project 'Pods')
(3 failures)** @wade zhou - MSFT

Comment: I have iOS 17 on my device

Comment: I used MacOS-13 agent and it worked fine

Comment: Glad to know it works with MacOS-13 agent. Since it has iOS17 on the agent. I added the answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `The Developer of app needs to update it to work with this version of iOS` indicates the app is `NOT compatible` with the iOS version on your DevOps agent.

As it's working on your local machine, and it has `iOS 17`. you can use `MacOS-13` agent as it has the version. `MacOS-12(MacOS-latest)` and `MacOS-11` doesn't have iOS17.

You can find the software list on the agent from [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software).